# UIImageView in UITableViewCell not animating when an animated UIImage is assigned twice

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm trying to display an animated UIImage in UITableViewCell's imageView. The animated image is shown after the first assignment but is not on every further attempt.

Here is the code of the TableViewController:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *animatedImage;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.animatedImage = [UIImage animatedImageNamed:@"syncing" duration:1.0];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static BOOL second = NO;

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (second) {

        cell.imageView.image = nil;
        NSLog(@"Removed image");
    }
    else {

        cell.imageView.image = self.animatedImage;
        NSLog(@"Added image");

        if (![cell.imageView isAnimating]) {

            [cell.imageView startAnimating];
            NSLog(@"Started animation for UIImageView: %@", cell.imageView);
        }
    }

    second = !second;

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}

@end
```

And this is the output when I tap the cell two times:

```
Added image
Started animation for UIImageView: <UIImageView: 0x7197540; frame = (0 0; 0 0); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; animations = { UIImageAnimation=<CAKeyframeAnimation: 0x715bc80>; }; layer = <CALayer: 0x71975a0>> - (null)
Removed image
Added image
Started animation for UIImageView: <UIImageView: 0x7197540; frame = (6 6; 30 30); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x71975a0>> - (null)
```

Comment: Check this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001043/why-does-my-animation-in-my-cell-disappear-when-the-cell-is-selected/33021637#33021637 It helped me with a similar problem.

Comment: I posted Answer here plz check: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34741997/4720315

Comment: @Pipo Do you solve the issue?

Comment: @andrey.krukovskiy I'm sorry, but I don't remember at all. This was 6 years ago. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest that you don't do any animation to the images in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` because if you have more images then an undesired effect will appear when you fast scroll (the cell images will switch due to cell re usability).

What I did in one of my projects, I implemented the `– scrollViewDidScroll:` method for the UITableViewDelegate (which conforms to UIScrollViewDelegate) and there I called a method that will animate the images only on the visible cells (tableView.visibleCells).

On the other hand I don't see why you are using the `static BOOL second = NO;` you could simply check if cell.imageView.image == nil or not.

Also check your animation code, it is possible that something is not working properly there (keep in mind that the cells are reused)
.

Comment: `- scrollViewDidScroll:` is called everytime the tableView scrolls just a few pixels. Did you mean `- scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:`?    I couldn't check for `(cell.imageView.image == nil)` because `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];` doesn't always return the same UITableViewCell.

Comment: It is ok in `-scrollViewDidScroll` to check for visible cells, because if you already did the proper changes the images won't change anymore. You can also change it in `-scrollViewDidEndDecelrating:` but the behaviour won't be as cool as if you do it in `-scrollViewDidScroll`

Comment: But `- scrollViewDidScroll:`is not called after `- tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`. And so the image wouldn't be animated if the user doesn't scroll. After testing a little further i'm sure that the problem has to do with the animation of the UITableViewCell that is shown before `- tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` is called. UIActivityIndicatorView works but isn't an UIAnimatedImage, i think.